# There is any problem in having multiple activities running together

Tags: android

I modified a TabHost to have more than one activity running at the same time, it works like a charm. But the question is, is there any problem when doing this?

I already checked the memory usage, and the isn't much difference in using a view and a activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are fine. There are no problems in doing that.